# Cloud Functions for Firebase Wildcard References in the function declaration

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between these two Cloud Functions declarations!?

```
exports.boxScoresUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Games/{gid}/BoxScores').onWrite(event => {
```

and

```
exports.emailEmployeeReport = functions.database.ref('/Employee/${eid}/reports').onWrite(event => {
```

Other then they reference different Nodes... the first function just has `{gid}` while the second function has `${eid}`

What is the `$` used for!? and does it actually matter (can you use them interchangeably) since my function works without the `$` as seen in the first database reference using only `{gid}`

Answer (score 4):

The first line is the correct expression for a wildcard variable in a database path.

The second line doesn't seem to be correct at all.  If it was using string variable interpolation with backticks (which it is not), it would include the current value of `eid` in the string, assuming it has been defined globally ahead of time.  Right now it is literally including the $ in the string path, which is most likely not what was intended.

If you got that line from [this video](https://youtu.be/NgZIb6Uwpjc?t=1m48s), notice in the comments that we acknowledged that is was a mistake in the typing and should not have included the dollar sign.